# How to locate code causing "Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

I got the warning message in ReactJS

> Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?

After deleting virtually every component in my routes.js file, I narrowed it down to a specific component in a file called `authenticationHandler.js`, however that file doesn't show up in the backtrace for the warning, which finishes with `warning.js:49` and lists several other files in the backtrace but not `authenticationHandler.js`

However, that approach was very tedious. How can I detect the code responsible for the warning in a more efficient manner?

For the record, I more or less understand the error message and what causes it: there was `<div class="foo">` when it should have been `<div className="foo">`

The warning in the console started with

```
warning.js:49Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?
warning @ warning.js:49
warnUnknownProperty @ DOMPropertyOperations.js:58
createMarkupForProperty @ DOMPropertyOperations.js:109
_createOpenTagMarkupAndPutListeners @ ReactDOMComponent.js:239
mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js:199
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:39
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:248
```

and this is a MCVE form of the render function:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div class="foo">
        </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: Project-wide search for `class={` or `class="` or `class='`?

Comment: @DanPrince `git grep -i "class\="` probably does that, but I'd like to be able to know how to handle other scenarios where I can't do a simple `git grep`.